# How to find the base case for a recursive function that changes a string of characters in a certain way

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming, discrete-mathematics

Lately I have been working with recursion as, according to my professor, it represents pure functional programming approach as neither changes on variables nor side effects take place. 
Through my previous two questions [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704084/how-to-write-a-recursive-function-that-takes-a-list-and-return-the-same-list-wit?noredirect=1#comment66726638_39704084) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641229/how-to-find-a-given-element-in-nested-lists/39648238?noredirect=1#comment66624227_39648238) I have come to realise that its not the recursive definition per say is my problem, I understand how a recursive definition work and I have tried solving many mathematics related questions using the recursive definition and managed to solve them on first try. Because in mathematics you always have a crystal clear base case such as `0!` is 1 etc. However when it comes to working with `string` it seems to be always the case that i have no idea how constitute my base case in form of :

```
if (something):
     return something
 else:
      invoke the recursive function
```

for example give a `list` of `string`, or `char` use a recursive definition to remove the vowels or alphanumeric `char` etc. As mention earlier its functional programming so no side effects no variable changes are permitted. Which raises the question, such questions are not mathematical how can one come up with base case?

Thanks everybody in advance for helping me to figure out my misery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're iterating over a list of characters, so your base case can be an empty string. Here's a quick example of a recursive function that removes vowels from a string:

```
def strip_vowels(str):
    if not str:
        return ''
    if str[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        return strip_vowels(str[1:])
    else:
        return str[0] + strip_vowels(str[1:])
```

Comment: Sorry, but as i mention in the question i have an answer to finding vowels question, in fact i have a multiple of them. I am looking for a sort of guided answer to approaching base cases for non-mathematical question that. Thanks for your effort though. Appreciate it much

Comment: Like in this example, an empty string or empty list will often act as a base case. Another way of looking at it is trying to think of how you can reduce the problem to a smaller one, and then dealing with the case which comes up when the problem has been maximally reduced. Or you can think about the "simplest" version of the problem that you can solve as a base case, such as an empty string or a string of one character, and work up from there.